# jQuery: Yahoo Autocomplete/Autosuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to retrieve yahoo autocomplete.

Yahoo's JSON url is this: http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip?output=fxjson&command=query

So I have:

```
   $("selector").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    "output" : "fxjson",
                    "command" : request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response(data[1])
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

And here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yQbdb/

Can someone spot a mistake or what I'm I doing wrong? It should work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `output` to `jsonp` works for me.

See [example query](http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip?output=jsonp&command=query) for the structure of the output.

The explanation is below.

Code is **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/Yj7kN/)**.

```
$("#wd6450").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                "output": "jsonp",
                "command": request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                // for each element in the data.gossip.results array ...
                $.each(data.gossip.results, function(i, val) {
                    // .. push the value of the key inside our array
                    suggestions.push(val.key);
                });
                // call response with our collected values
                response(suggestions);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**

By using `dataType: "jsonp"` jQuery expects the output format to be in JSONP. When you make a call from your code using `output: "fxjson"` the URL looks like **[this](http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip?callback=jQuery17108331644597928971_1323059362318&output=fxjson&command=ao&_=1323059367787)** but as you can see the output is not a valid JSONP, because the callback was not called.

On the other hand when you specify `output: "jsonp"` the query looks like **[this](http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip?callback=jQuery171043398347147740424_1323059216818&output=jsonp&command=aol&_=1323059223832)** and as you can see the output is a valid JSONP - the callback was called.

You linked a Amazon example in the comments. `$.ajax()` call there will try to URL like **[this](http://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?callback=jQuery17103970956518314779_1323059130801&search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=ao&_=1323059144257)**. Output from Amazon's webservice is valid JSONP, because callback is called with all the data.

So the result is: Yahoo webservices will return format in JSONP if you provide `?output=jsonp` parameter in the URL by configuring `$.ajax()` with `output: "jsonp"`. Amazon's webservice returns this format by default without any extra parameters. This is webservice specific configuration and must be consulted with its documentation or other related resourcers.

Information about JSONP available **[HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)**.

Comment: Well it is correct but it doesn't make sense to me. Can you please break it down to me so I can use it in the future too? Because imagine I'm using ebay's autosuggest: http://anywhere.ebay.com/services/suggest/?q=test which has no output etc. Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast Setting `output`  to `fxjson` was making `$.ajax` angry because JSONP callback was not getting called. I found it by adding an error handler to the ajax call. Then I tried to change the `output` and it started to work.

Comment: JSONP is getting called from dataType. And in case you had to set the output to jsonp how does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/HaQTA/ ?

Comment: @jQuerybeast: But `dataType: "jsonp"` is a option for `$.ajax` and not a parameter for the yahoo gossip webservice. As you can see changing the `output` forces webservice to provide data in a different form which is working with the `$.ajax` configured for JSONP.

Comment: Thank you. Now it sounds more straight forward. Can you explain me the last 3 lines with the data.gossip.results please? What if it wasn't gossip, do you always have to set data.[last url path].results, ?

Comment: @jQuerybeast I wrote a long explanation - see the answer. There are also short comments in the code. See [jQuery.each() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and the output from the webservice for more details :).

Comment: Thanks much! Now I understood why you used gossip. To select the array. What if didn't had array? Like this one: http://anywhere.ebay.com/services/suggest/?v=jsonp&q=test Would you use each element of the val of the query or leave it empty? Sorry for asking much but I'm asking to learn like most who just want things ready. Thanks

Comment: @jQuerybeast: The structure returned by Amazon's webservice contains an array of all results which is available by accessing 2nd element of the returned array `a[1]`. In Yahoo's structure you must process the data in a more complicated way to retrieve array of "terms". In case of any more questions (like other services, questions about arrays, etc) please create a new question on stackoverflow.